# Java Cup IllegalAccessException exporting jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I'm trying to export my java cup project from eclipse as a runnable jar, the export is done correctly but when i try to run it i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class Parser with modifiers "public static"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

What's going wrong?

**Edit:**
I solved the problem by repacking the required libraries in the generated Jar

Answer (score 0):

class Parser must be declared as a public class. This should solve your problem.

```
public class Parser{

....

}
```